Can we rule out the possibility that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is small modulo every prime?
Consider a prime $p$ such that the polynomial $X^3-2$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_p$: $X^3-2 = (X-\alpha_p)(X-\beta_p)(X-\gamma_p)$. It seems reasonable to expect that (identifying $\alpha_p,\beta_p,\gamma_p$ with numbers in $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$) the ratios $\alpha_p/p,\beta_p/p,\gamma_p/p \in [0,1)$ should be uniformly distributed (this expectation is, at the very least, strongly hinted at in Equidistribution of Roots of a Quadratic Congruence to Prime Moduli by W. Duke, J. B. Friedlander and H. Iwaniec). To be a little more precise, I would expect that if we look at the set of points
$$S_N = \{ \alpha_p/p : p < N \} \cup \{ \beta_p/p : p < N \} \cup \{ \gamma_p/p : p < N \}$$ then for each interval $[x,y) \subset [0,1)$ the ratio $\#( S_N \cap [x,y))/\# S_N$ should converge to $y-x$ as $N \to \infty$. This, however, seems to be an open problem: the analogous question for quadratic polynomials was solved by Duke, Friedlander and Iwaniec, and as far as I'm aware the same problem for higher degrees is considered difficult.
I am curious if a weaker statement can be proved. Specifically, can we disprove that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ and all sufficiently large primes $p$ we have $\alpha_p/p \in [0,\varepsilon)$? In other words, can we show that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $X^3-2$ does not have a root modulo $p$ in $\{0,1,2,\dots, \lfloor\varepsilon p\rfloor\}$? By  pigeonhole argument (using the fact that $n^3-2$ can be divisible by at most two primes larger than $n$) one can disprove that for almost all primes $p$ we have $\alpha_p/p \in [0, c/\log p)$ for a constant $c > 0$.

You might be able to take advantage of the fact that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^3 - 2y^3$, a theorem of Heath-Brown from 2001. There is some flexibility in his argument to choose the sectors. This has been refined recently by Xiannan Li, where he showed that you still get infinitely many primes even when $y$ is restricted to a short interval.

The first sentence makes no sense to me. What does the prime p have to do with whether or not the polynomial splits into linear factors? And over what ring is the polynomial defined?

@DanielAsimov: we factor the polynomial over ${\mathbb F}_p$.

The primes for which $x^3 -2$  factors into three linears are $p = u^2 + 27 v^2.$  Gauss.   See http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

That there is a $\varepsilon>0$ for which we can disprove the statement for all smaller numbers, I think, follows from Cilleruelo's conjecture for the polynomial in question, and specifically we can take $\varepsilon=1/12$.

Ah, I see Maynard-Rudnick proved the upper bound part of the conjecture, which I think is enough for my 1/12 statement.

@DrorSpeiser I think in order to disprove the statement we would need a good lower bound on lcm of $n^3-2$ for $n$ up to some threshold $N$, but Maynard-Rudnick are mostly concerned with getting a lower bound. As far as I was able to see, they only  use the trivial upper bound (lcm is at most as large as the product). It could well be that I'm missing something, or perhaps we're talking about different papers?

Ah you're right, I had an error in computation.

Can you guys elaborate on the implication from Cilleruelo's conjecture to the question? I don't see how Cilleruelo detects anything about intervals as long as $\epsilon p$ (it does with shorter intervals of size $O(p/\log p)$), moreover it seems to only be sensitive to pairs of roots in the short interval. But I may be missing something.
